# MongoDB is reporting zero when I use db.<collection_name>.count()

Tags: mongodb

I am pretty sure my problem is that I interrupted a query, I just don't know how to recover. Even though I can see that my db is over **60GB** when I use `db.<collection_name>.count()` I get **0**. I have exited. I have tried `db.repairDatabase()`. `db.stats()` gives a zero for everything. `db.getMongo()` shows a connection to localhost.

I expect to get a non zero value when I use `db.<collection_name>.count()`. So now I am stumped on what to try next, please help.

Comment: You have mentioned whatever you tried and not working but not mentioning anything about what do you want to do actually, I mean what do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect a non zero result, because I got that before something went wrong.

Comment: Are you using `db.<actual_collection_name>.count()`?

Comment: Yes, and I have used the use commands to get into the correct db and collection, which gives me the happy switched to <collection> but still no results

Comment: Have you tried the count for all the collections?

Comment: Did you mean db.printCollectionStats() ? I still got 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WiredTiger storage engine, inaccurate count result could happen when the database did not shutdown cleanly. In [Accuracy after Unexpected Shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown):

> After an unclean shutdown of a mongod using the Wired Tiger storage engine, count statistics reported by count() may be inaccurate.

As mentioned in the link, running:

```
db.<collection>.validate()
```

should restore the correct count.

Comment: I tried and got:  db.RDC_NUS.validate()
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "ns not found", "valid" : false } and my count is still zero

Comment: Is this a standalone node, replica set, or sharded cluster?

Comment: Also, if you do `db.<collection>.find()`, does it return anything?

Comment: [`code`](db.<collection>.find()) produced no result. This is a replica set with two other servers, I am not the admin. The other two sets say not master, which I think is good, right?

Comment: In a replica set, there can be only one Primary node, others will be Secondaries (i.e. not master in `db.isMaster()` output). See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/. However, if `validate()` returns `ns not found` and `find()` returns nothing, the collection essentially doesn't exist. How did you find that the collection is using 60 GB?